# How is an instantiated object treated inside of an if statement?

Tags: php, object, boolean

For handling the conversion to strings, the magic method __toString() exists in php. However, if I have an instantiated object, such as:

```
$myObj = new Object();
$myObj->doSomeThings();

if ($myObj) {
    // Some stuff to do here
}
```

How can I tell PHP what to do while evaluating the $myObj in the if conditional?

The main reason I am curious, is that I would like to have a chainable method that will also directly evaluate conditionally in an if statement.

```
if ($myObj->chainMethodA($var)->chainMethodA($var2)->chainMethodB($var)) {
```

Given that all these methods do:

```
return $this;
```

How can I handle the boolean evaluation of the object based upon a class attribute, such as:

```
$this->switch = true;
```

I know I could always do *this*:

```
if ($myObj->chainMethodA($var)->chainMethodA($var2)->chainMethodB($var)->switch) {
```

But I would prefer to handle that automatically.

Comment: Why not create your own getter function, something like `function getSwitch(){ return $this->switch; }`?

Comment: I bet I'm wrong here, but can't you just override the `__toString` method in that object?

Comment: @BrianGraham Yes, but will that method even be called in an if statement like that?

Comment: @elclanrs Yes, I can always do that. I don't want to because I'm using this as an API object. I want to assume the developer always forgets the final method call.

Comment: Could simply give it a shot and see if it works? I can't test it on my end at the moment.

Comment: @BrianGraham You would most likely have to cast it "if ((string) $myObj) {" for it to trigger the tostring method

Answer (score 0):

This is a matter of code preference.

if you are using method chaining, you can chain them in the loop as you sugested. this originates for ugly IF statements but works fine.

another way to do this is call every method and then check for the switch (using on not a getter).

so you have this:

```
$myObj = new Object();
$myObj->doSomeThings();
$myObj->chainMethodA($var)->chainMethodA($var2)->chainMethodB($var);
```

for the if you can:

```
if( $myObj->switch ){
...
}
```

or

```
if( $myObj->switchState() ){
..
}
```

however, what i sugest is wrap your functions in another bool method, or another class, so all you have to do is:

```
$myObj = new Object();
if( $myObj->doAlotOfThings($var1,$var2) ){

}
```